# How to evaluate the limit of $f$ and find the domain of $f$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

Let this function :
$$
f\left( x\right) =\dfrac{\sqrt{2x}-\sqrt{2}}{x^{3}-5x^{2}+8x-4}
$$
How can I determine the domain of $f$ ?

How can I evaluate algebrically the following in its simplest and exact form?

$$
\lim _{x\rightarrow 1}f\left( x\right) 
$$

I tried using the quadratic formula but the gradient was negative. What should do to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

You can factor out the denominator as follows:
\begin{align*}
x^{3} - 5x^{2} + 8x - 4 = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow  (x^{3} - x^{2}) - (4x^{2} - 4x) + (4x - 4) =0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow  x^{2}(x-1) - 4x(x-1) + 4(x-1) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x^{2} - 4x + 4)(x-1) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x-2)^{2}(x-1) = 0
\end{align*}

Consequently, the proposed limit is the same as:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt{2x} - \sqrt{2}}{x^{3} - 5x^{2} + 8x - 4} & = \lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{x} - 1)}{(x-2)^{2}(x-1)}\\\\
& = \lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{(x-2)^{2}(\sqrt{x} + 1)}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding domain: $\sqrt{x}$ is only defined when $x \geq 0$. This means that $\sqrt{2x}$ is only defined when $2x \geq 0$ and therefore $x \geq 0$. Secondly, $\frac{1}{x}$ is only defined when $x \neq 0$ therefore $\frac{1}{x^3 - 5x^2 + 8x - 4} = \frac{1}{(x-2)^2(x-1)}$ is only defined when $x \neq 2$ or $x \neq 1$.
Overall the domain is $D = \{x \geq 0, x \neq 1, 2\}$.

Regarding the limit, you could use Epsilon-Delta proof or you could notice that $$\frac{\sqrt{2x}-\sqrt2}{x^3 - 5x^2 + 8x - 4} = \frac{\sqrt2(\sqrt{x}-1)}{(x-2)^2(x-1)} = \frac{\sqrt2(\sqrt{x}-1)(\sqrt{x}+1)}{(x-2)^2(x-1)(\sqrt{x}+1)}$$ $$= \frac{\sqrt2(x-1)}{(x-2)^2(x-1)(\sqrt{x}+1)} = \frac{\sqrt2}{(x-2)^2(\sqrt{x}+1)}$$
And clearly the limit as $x \to 1$, $\frac{\sqrt2}{(x-2)^2(\sqrt{x}+1)} \to \frac{\sqrt2}{(1-2)^2(\sqrt{1}+1)} = \frac{\sqrt2}{2}$

Hope this helps!